TN-S Earthing System
I wanted to give a good explanation about the installation that i have to examine. I want to explain that it has a TN-S earthing system.
I have conducted several measurements, and they yielded a loop impedance of 58 ohms for the L-PE measurement, 60 ohms for the L-N measurement, and 155 ohms for the L-L measurement. My professor mentioned that this already indicates it is a TN system. Why? To specifically indicate that it is a TN-S earthing system, can you simply demonstrate by stating that from the star point of the transformer, the PE and N have different sections?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to know why it is a TN-earthing system because of the L-N and L-PE loop-impedance being equal. My second question is: how can you determine it is a TN-S earthing system? I get that there should be a seperate N and PE, but is that enough evidence?
